# declaring and using global variables express js

Tags: node.js, express, global-variables

In one router I want to get some variables and I want to use them in another router. Is the best way to use a middleware (and if so, how to do it)? If I just a declare global variable at the beginning of the server, will it not lead to unexpected behavior if multiple users or requests are handled simultaneously (it's a react native app, not a browser?

```js
const { Station } = require("../models/station");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
var deviceId;
var directionNumber;
var metroNumberChoice;
router.post("/postUserDirectionAndLineNumberAndDeviceId", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    directionNumber = req.body.direction;
    deviceId = req.body.deviceId;
    metroNumberChoice = req.body.metroNumberChoice;
    res.status(200).json({ message: "User direction received successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
});
router.post("/getlocation", (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log("deviceId", deviceId);
    const findMetro = async () => { 
      console.log(
        "directionNumber:",
        directionNumber,
        "metroNumberChoice:",
        metroNumberChoice,
        "deviceId:",
        deviceId
      );
       
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: You want to use a session

Answer (score 1):

In the snippet you shared, there's no coupling between the two routes that handle the same global state.

You could get a request from user X to `postUserDirectionAndLineNumberAndDeviceId` that updates the global variables, and then a request from user Y to the same route that would **overwrite them**. Then, the original user X could send a request to `getlocation` and get the details of user Y instead of their own details.

A more robust solution could be to use a session, e.g. with the [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) middleware.

Comment: for hours i was trying to figure this out, ai says that:
In general, using req.session to store global variables is not considered a good practice. Here are the main reasons why:req.session is accessible within the scope of a single request. Storing global variables there can lead to unexpected behavior as other requests might not have access to the same session data.